# In Android How to Restart App On Click Application "onGoing" Notification. if App is open or not

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, notifications, android-service

In Android How to Restart App On Click Application "onGoing" Notification. if App is open or not.

Like As When i Click on onGoing Notification "Connected as a Media device"

Answer (score 0):

You can define actions you want to happen when interacting with your Notification by adding a `PendingIntent`.

In the following example a `PendingIntent` is created to launch the (current) activity. 
That intent is then added to the notification in the content section. Once this notification is shown, when you click the content section, the intent is fired and the app gets started  or brought back to top.

```
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
...
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationCompat.Builder nb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
        0);
nb.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha) 
    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_STATUS) 
    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
    .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.app_name))
    .setContentText("Click to launch!")
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent) // Here the "onClick" Intent is added
    .setOngoing(false);

nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, nb.build());
```

In this case the notification is dismissable. If you set `.setOngoing(true)` you need to remove it by calling `.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID)` on an instance of the NotificationManager.

See also this introduction on how to [Build a Notification](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html).